# Formatting an RSS Feed Date and Time

Tags: javascript, php, xslt, rss

I have an RSS Feed I used FeedRoll to create it an i am pulling it in via xslt into my site. My question is what formatting via javascript would I have to create to format my dates to not look like:

December 04, 2013  05:00:00 am

**and instead look like:**

Dec 4, 2013 5:00PM

**The script FeedRoll provides is:**

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.feedroll.com/rssviewer/feed2js.php?
src=http%3A%2F%2Frss.cnn.com%2Frss%2Fcnn_topstories.rss&num=5&date=y&tz=+n/-
n/'feed'&utf=y"  charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**which displays like this:**
[image]

It looks like this particular feed is driven by php and the offset set to: +n/-n/'feed' but this mean's nothing to me. **How do I get the month to become shortened an the zero's aligned like what I am looking for above?**

I am assuming Javascript is the easiest way to go... logically i am stuck.

****Update**** (here's how my stylesheet looks):

```
  <xsl:template name="news_feed">
     <script language="JavaScript" src="{RSSSrc}"  charset="UTF-8"
                type="text/javascript"></script>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="NewsPage">
    <div class="news-block">
        <div class="holder">
            Image goes here...
            <div class="section">
                <dl>
                    <xsl:call-template name="news_feed"/>
                </dl>
                </div>
           </div>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: I think it would be best to do this upstream. Can you post your XSLT stylesheet?

Comment: @user3016153 i just updated my question.

Comment: Well, the money is in the "news_feed" template which is not shown. IMHO, to customize beyond what's offered by FeedRoll, you might just as well go directly to the RSS source. It's very easy to turn an Atom feed into HTML, which you can then apply your own CSS style to. OTOH, I see that the original CNN feed provides the timestamp as `Tue, 03 Dec 2013 20:59:45 EST`. If you need to change the time zone and/or convert to 12-hour format, you might want to do it by Javascript anyway.

Comment: @user3016153 why is it not shown? it's the first template... Consisting of a javascript line.

Comment: @nl-x I mean we don't see what it *does*. We would need to see the javascript it points to for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I quickly could Google is that Feedroll offers only this format for dates. (with the option of setting a custom timezone)

If you really oppose this, all you can do is set an onload function that gets all elements with class `rss-date`, then parses the `innerText` to a Date object. And then outputs it again to the date format of your choosing.

**edit:** here is an implementation in javascript with jquery.

The hardest part wasn't even the selecting and parsing. But actually just formatting the string to what you want. With a small amount of work you can even strip out all jquery, if you don't like using it.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function myFormat(dateTime) {
    var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
    var dateString = months[dateTime.getMonth()] + ' ' + dateTime.getDate() + ', ' + dateTime.getFullYear();
    var timeString;
    if (dateTime.getHours() == 0)
        timeString = "12:" + (dateTime.getMinutes()<10?"0"+dateTime.getMinutes():dateTime.getMinutes()) + "AM";
    else if (dateTime.getHours() < 12)
        timeString = dateTime.getHours() + ":" + (dateTime.getMinutes()<10?"0"+dateTime.getMinutes():dateTime.getMinutes()) + "AM";
    else if (dateTime.getHours() == 12)
        timeString = "12:" + (dateTime.getMinutes()<10?"0"+dateTime.getMinutes():dateTime.getMinutes()) + "PM";
    else
        timeString = (dateTime.getHours()-12) + ":" + (dateTime.getMinutes()<10?"0"+dateTime.getMinutes():dateTime.getMinutes()) + "PM";
    return dateString + ' ' + timeString;
}
$(document).ready(function() {$('.rss-date').each(function() {$(this).text(myFormat(new Date($(this).text())));});});
</script>
```

Comment: Yes I figured this out on my own... feed roll only allows you to pull timezone or simple format. I am trying to overwrite this format... parsing innerText to a date object sounds like overkill...could this be the only way to overwrite this format? if so, how would this be written? @nl-x

Comment: very very close... for some reason the time offset is showing up as -7:0PM... @nl-x

Comment: yeah, i know. you probably already took the code before i edited it a second time. try it now

Comment: oh but wait... now the PM's are showing up as the AM's... im sure i can figure this one out. just looked at it.

Comment: an to add... would there be any way to remove the '5:00PM' and instead make it show up as '5 PM' instead? @nl-x

Comment: what do you mean the PM's are showing up as the AM's ? I tested it and it works fine. Double check. And sure you can change 5:00 AM to 5 AM. Just change the javascript function myFormat...

Comment: nevermind... i simply changed the AM's to PM's... seem to be working fine now... THanks @nl-x

Comment: @MizAkita Are you sure ?!?! Or are you confused on what AM and PM mean? (0:00 -> 11:59 = 12:00AM - 11:59AM. And 12:00 - 23:59 = 12:00PM - 11:59PM.) Or are you on a different timezone?

Comment: no im not confused... just had to re-define the offset i think. I am on PST @nl-x